# simple mySQL query!

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-logic

EDIT:
MY BAD! I had a stray line screwing it up

```
$uid = json_encode($uid);
```

Comment: you have a table for each user?

Comment: What is the problem ? Can you explain better the problem ?

Comment: Whether it is correct or wrong depends on what you are trying to achieve... What results are you expecting, and what are you getting? If you get an error message, what does it say?

Comment: Umm, all I can say is that the query seems to be syntactically correct. You will need to show the table definitions and tell us what you're trying to do, and what you get instead, before anybody can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have uid_$uid in there. Maybe that's your problem.